# How to get asterisk value from BASH input

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

Following is the input from command line:

```
bash script.sh "input*" ";" "21" "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

and in my current directory i have two input files:

- input1.txt
- input2.txt

While i want to get value **'input*'** from input **'$1'** i got **'input1.txt input2.txt'** as input.

Is there any way to get value **'input*'** from **'$1'**?

Answer (score -1):

you can use `"$1"` where `1` is the number of first input parameter

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
```

but you have to pass the `input*.txt` like this `input\*.txt`

output

```
[shell] ➤ ./test7.sh input\*.txt
input*.txt
```

Regards

Claudio

Comment: The quoting, not the braces, are the beef here.

Comment: @tripleee, what do you mean?

Comment: Your answer reads as if the braces were important, but they are completely superfluous here.

Comment: you read it in that way.. I didn't wrote that the braces are most important then quoting..

Comment: Partly that, partly because of other issues (the backslash vs quoting discussion is similarly misdirected), partly because this is a FAQ and so it should simply be closed as duplicate, instead of answered.

Comment: I don't have the close permission .. btw have a nice a day